# Capturing JSON on existing web server through flume

Tags: json, apache, hadoop, flume

I’ve got two load balanced vanilla apache nodes receiving JSON POST requests from a SaaS where the entire body of the JSON POST needs to be flumed to HDFS. I had thought about using the exec source type and tailing the apache logs, but those don’t log POST requests without having to use something like mod_dumpio. Additionally, the JSON is not structured like a typical common or custom web log, so when it streams to the flume collector as-is seems to have the collector barking about missing date/time stamps.

I’m not seeing a lot of good implementation online about using HTTPSource as a source type, but it seems it needs to fire up it’s own listener and I have an existing vhost on port 80 (and more on the way) that I simply want to stream the JSON as-is to HDFS.

This seems like a super simple way to use flume and has worked great in the past with standard apache logs, but incoming JSON POST’s to HDFS has me stumped.

Here's my flume agent conf. Any guidance on using a source type of HTTPSource would be very helpful! Thanks.

```
agent.sources = apache
agent.sources.apache.type = exec
agent.sources.apache.command = tail -f /usr/local/webserver-proxy/localhost/logs/msgsys_access_log
agent.sources.apache.batchSize = 1
agent.sources.apache.channels = memoryChannel

agent.channels = memoryChannel
agent.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory
agent.channels.memoryChannel.capacity = 1000

## Send to Flume Collector at flume.XXXX.int (Hadoop Flume Node)
# http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#avro-sink
agent.sinks = AvroSink
agent.sinks.AvroSink.type = avro
agent.sinks.AvroSink.channel = memoryChannel
agent.sinks.AvroSink.hostname = flume.XXXX.int
agent.sinks.AvroSink.port = 4164
```